# Get rid of repeated fields in a log line

Tags: powershell

I have logs lines in which the information fields are repeated, the first time they are separated by a comma and a space, the second time they are separated by a semicolon, I want to get rid of their second occurrence, the word (SECOND) is not in the log, I put it there to make it more clear

```
targets:somehost state:Memory\Buffers=398672, Memory\Cached=4620216, Memory\MemFree=833748, Memory\MemTotal=8001352 (SECOND) Memory\Buffers=398672;Memory\Cached=4620216;Memory\MemFree=833748;Memory\MemTotal=8001352  type:Unix Resources
```

I Was thinking in using replace.

```
 %{$_ -replace "Memory\\Buffers=([0-9]+);Memory\\Cached=([0-9]+);Memory\\MemFree=([0-9]+);Memory\\MemTotal=([0-9]+)",""}
```

but the log has a lot more fields, that I din't put in here to make it more readable.
is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `$_ -replace '(?<=Memory\\Buffers=.*?)\s*Memory\\Buffers.*$'`

Comment: That was great, but also deleted a non repeated field at the end of the log:  "type:Unix Resources"

Comment: End up using this: (?<=Memory\\Buffers=.*?)\s*Memory\\Buffers.*(?=(\stype)), based on @MathiasR.Jessen answer

Comment: Add a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove everything starting from (and including) the second occurrence of `Memory\Buffers=` with a positive [look-*behind* assertion (`(?<=...)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind)):

```
$string -replace '(?<=Memory\\Buffers=.*?)\s*Memory\\Buffers.*$'
```

As you've found, with a positive [look-*ahead* assertion (`(?=...)`)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) you can then specify where the second sequence stops:

```
$string -replace '(?<=Memory\\Buffers=.*?)\s*Memory\\Buffers.*(?=\stype:)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your log lines follow the pattern of your sample line, and assuming that *all* fields following `state:` are repeated, you can use the following regex (using a simplified input string, in which the fields `Me\Bu=398672` and `Me\Ca=4620216` are repeated):

```
'a:b c:Me\Bu=398672, Me\Ca=4620216 Me\Bu=398672;Me\Ca=4620216  d:e f' | % {
  $_ -replace '[^ ]+;[^ ]+  '
}
```

The above yields:

```
a:b c:Me\Bu=398672, Me\Ca=4620216 d:e f
```

- `[^ ]+;` matches the first field in the *second* occurrence of the fields list.
- `[^ ]+` matches all remaining fields in the second list.